# Git ignore except specific subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I've looked at some examples on how to ignore everything except certain sub directories like so.

```
# Ignore Everything
foo/*
# Include sub directory
!foo/ccc/*
```

I have also tried:

```
# Ignore Everything
foo/*
# Include sub directory
!foo/ccc/
```

**UPDATE**

So the code above works, however trying to exclude a directory within another directory within another does not work. It only works on the parent directory and sub directory.

```
# Ignore Everything
foo/*
# Include sub directory
!foo/ccc/aaa/ddd/
```

After I include this in my gitingore, I run a `git add --all` and I dont see any the files in `git status`.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any files in `/foo/ccc`? Git will ignore empty directories.

Comment: @mamapitufo Yes, I have many files in ccc

Comment: I just tried with the second variation and it works in a test repository... is something else ignoring the `foo/` directory?

Comment: @mamapitufo I read that as well, but i'm unsure how other people have managed it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Comment: Negative, that's the only ignore I have on foo.

Comment: @mamapitufo updated my question, take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unignore every directory in the path that you wish to unignore. Something like the following should work in your case:

```
# Ignore everything in foo
foo/*
# Except the ccc subdir
!foo/ccc

# Ignore everything in ccc subdir
foo/ccc/*
# Except the aaa subsubdir
!foo/ccc/aaa

# Ignore everything in aaa subsubdir
foo/ccc/aaa/*
# Except the ddd subsubsubdir
!foo/ccc/aaa/ddd
```

It's important that the ignore rules end in `/*`, as that tells git to ignore everything in the folder, but not the folder itself, permitting us to add exceptions to the ignore rules for specific subdirectories.