# Source\config\config.inc.ahk is ignored by git

Tags: git, gitignore

i using the .gitignore below.
surprisingly it ignores the file Source\config\config.inc.ahk

last line tried whitelist **all** files and subfolders in the source folder 
`!Source/**`

Therefore i expected that Source\config\config.inc.ahk is not ignored.
How could i fix that?

UPDATE: This may answerd my question: **You have to unignore every directory in the path that you wish to unignore.** [Git ignore except specific subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037838/git-ignore-except-specific-subdirectories)

what i have tried:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Whitelist some files
!.gitignore
!README.md

# Whitelist folder files files, and subfolders
!Source/**
```

(complete .gitignore: https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build/blob/master/.gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+unignore+subdirectory

Comment: After ignoring everything you need to unignore `/Source/` before ungnoring `/Source/*`: `!/Source/`.

Comment: yes this works. `!Source/` followed by `!Source/**` . so sad to need for this two comands. I do not see any sense in it. It seems to me `!Source/**` should be clear enough. I hope in a future version, no two commands are needed anymore.

Comment: After `*` the unignore directive `!Source/**` is not consulted at all. I don't think this will be changed.

Comment: @phd ok  its not be consulted at all. then it is in my opinion a design flaw. Because what else should it mean? Better just use one line, which is easy to understand. I think this line alone is also good to understand. Or not?